# Можно ли подменить trait в тесте?

Tags: php, phpunit

У меня есть класс, часть функционала в котором реализует trait.
Чтобы все протестировать необходимо данный trait подменить на свой (тестовый).

Как это можно сделать ?

Comment: можете унаследовать класс от исходного и подключить к нему тестовый трейт, методы перекроются последним трейтом.

Comment: Да, да. Зашло. Спасибо. Скопируйте в ответ, я тыкну галку.

Comment: написал ответом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наиболее простым решением будет унаследовать новый класс от исходного и подключить к нему тестовый трейт, который спрячет методы исходного трейта.

То есть если у нас есть исходный трейт и класс:

```
trait SrcTrait {
    public function check(){
        echo "src-trait";
    }
}

class Test {
    use SrcTrait;
}
```

а также тестовый трейт:

```
trait TestTrait {
    public function check(){
        echo "test-trait";
    }
}
```

то при проведении тестов мы создаем новый класс наследник и подключаем к нему тестовый трейт.

```
class Test2 extends Test {
    use TestTrait;
}

$x = new Test2();
$x->check();
```

Comment: Да четко, спасибо. Еще подсказали как вариант использовать анонимный класс. Но подход один в один.

Comment: @Nepster да, с анонимный удобнее даже, но это только в php7. `$x = new class extends Test { use TestTrait; };`